# Index already exists with different options error while using createIndex() in latest MongoDB java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-java

So I am upgrading the MongoDB java driver to 2.12.4 where the `ensureIndex()` method has been deprecated. I am instead using the `createIndex()` method which from the docs seems like to funciton similarly to `ensureIndex()`. However, when I use this method in production, I get the following error -

```
{ "serverUsed" : "X.X.X.X" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Index with name: <index_name> already exists with different options" , "code" : 85}
```

Why does this happen? Could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try removing your current indexes before you create the new ones.

If you're worried about production downtime etc for these indexes, you could:

1. Add a second index just like the one you have on production now
   with a different name.
2. delete the existing one
3. restart the server so that the index in your Java code is created as expected
4. delete your duplicate index.

Answer (score 8):

Will Shaver's answer is very good, however doesn't actually address the issue the gravetii is highlighting.

`createIndex` will fail with this error if you are trying to create an index on the same fields, with the same order, but with different options.  This is because the indexes options may cause the index have very different properties.  This is obvious when you consider an index with the `unique` flag.

If you call `createIndex` with the same fields, the same order, and the same options, it will behave as you expect; making no change to the collection's indexes, and it will not throw an exception.

Comment: can you please clarify how different options look like ?

Comment: They may look very different depending on your situation Firoj.  Feel free to checkout Mongo's own documentation for your use case: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/