# sails js - error when clean the collections in start up

Tags: sails.js, waterline

In my sails application I edit the config/models.js file as follows to clean the database when lifting the application.

```
  migrate: 'drop',
  connection: 'mongodb'
```

But when I try to run the application it displays the following error.

```
A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
MongoError: Index with name: _id_ already exists with different options
```

I am using sails version 0.10.5 ,any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

same here, when you have an error to the model the orm crashes, at least you have the error, sometimes with mysql you don't even have the error

Answer (score 0):

the issue was, in some of my application's model files I have added following to attributes list.

```
attributes: {
    _id: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true
    }
}
```

since I have added unique true to the attribute, it causes an error when I try to clean the collections on start up. more information about this issue can be found on [Index already exists with different options error while using createIndex() in latest MongoDB java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288373/index-already-exists-with-different-options-error-while-using-createindex-in-l)